# Copying values from other columns based on boolean

Tags: r, dataframe, calculated-columns

I have a dataframe like the following (but with several thousand rows):

```
 x   a   b    c
[1]  1   2  True
[2]  4   7  False
[3]  5   3  False
[4]  9   6  True
```

I need a function to copy values from a and b over based on c (a if True, b if False). So it should become

```
 x   a   b   c
[1]  1   2   1
[2]  4   7   7
[3]  5   3   3
[4]  9   6   9
```

I've tried using lapply, didn't work.
Tried

```
x$c <- if (x$c) x$a else x$b
```

also didn't work. They spat out errors like "condition has length >1 and only the first element will be used". Even somehow managed to delete the column once.

What can I use to do this? I don't want to use a loop if I can avoid it because the iteration will take forever

Answer (score 3):

We can use row/column index which would be fast

```
 x$c <- x[cbind(1:nrow(x),(x$c=='False')+1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may do like this,

```
x$c <- ifelse(x$c=="True" ,x$a , x$b)
```

Comment: Could also be written as `with(x, ifelse(as.logical(c), a, b))` since there's an `as.logical.factor` method and also an internal method for characters written as `True`

Comment: @user2087999 - I am guessing you have factor columns, and `ifelse()` returned their integer values.  Please provide the output of `dput(head(x))` in your question.